# Turn off MySQL --skip-grant -tables

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I reset my root `mysql` password with the following instructions:

(Works for Ubuntu as well)
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/442

But now I can't turn off `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`.

When I run `fg` I have:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

How can I kill this and start MySQL securely?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely just kill the process.

killall -9 mysqld

http://anothermysqldba.blogspot.com/search/label/--skip-grant-tables